# CSS Full-Width Grid - Columns with Even Margins

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to make a responsive grid with 4 columns that fills the whole width of the screen on the desktop version, but adding margins to space them out in-between obviously means that the last column either doesn't fill the remaining width of the screen, or drops down into a new row, depending on the widths the columns are given.

CSS:

```
#servicesGrid
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.service
{
width:24.75%;
height:45%;
background:#262626;
display:block;
float:left;
margin:1px;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(1)
{
width:100%;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(2)
{
margin-left:0;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(5)
{
margin-right:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="servicesGrid">

    <div class="service"></div>

    <div class="service"></div>

    <div class="service"></div>

    <div class="service"></div>

    <div class="service"></div>

</div>
```

Example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4bw4p3LL/.

Comment: Some quick suggestions: You can try to use paddings instead of margins. Or take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid (if you have the liberty/will to include bootstrap). Alternatively use bootstrap on an example and steal the technique they use for your own code.

Comment: see my answer below. i explained it the best i could. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `%` for `width` , i suggest you use `%` for margins also. so you will be sure you add up to `100%` .

the idea is that `4*colwidth + 3*margins = 100%`

so, using a `margin-right:0.5%` to all `.col` elements except the last one ( `nth-of-type(5)` ) , then you will have the width of `100% - 3*0.5% = 98.5% / 4 = 24.625%`

where:  `100%` is the width of the `servicesGrid`, `3` is the number of `0.5%` margins given to the first 3 cols, `98.5%` is the remaining space occupied by the 4 col, and dividing it by the nr of col gives you the width of every col

```css
#servicesGrid
{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.service
{
 width:24.625%;
 height:45%;
 background:#262626;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin:1px 0.5% 1px 0;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(5)
{
 margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="servicesGrid">
   
    <div id="serviceWide" class="service col" style="width:100%; margin:0 0 1px 0">
    </div>
    
    <div class="service col"></div>
    
    <div class="service col"></div>
    
    <div class="service col"></div>
    
    <div class="service col"></div>
    
   </div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `calc` for the `width`. This will allow you to specify a value (the `margin`) to subtract from the `width`. Just be aware of the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), which is all modern browsers.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bw4p3LL/1/)

```
.service {    
    width: calc(24.75% - 1px);
    height: 45%;
    background: #262626;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Good idea but leaves a gap to the right of the fourth column

Answer (score 0):

One option is use a `border` to fake the space between elements, then you can use `box-sizing` to include the border inside the `width`. Try this code:

```css
#servicesGrid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.service {
  width: 25%;
  height: 45%;
  background: #262626;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.service:nth-child(n+3) {
   border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="servicesGrid">
  <div id="serviceWide" class="service col" style="width:100%; margin:0 0 1px 0"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
</div>
```

---

## Second Option

If you can use [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), then try this code:

```css
#servicesGrid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content:flex-start;
  align-items:justyfy-content;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#serviceWide {
  flex:0 1 100%;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
.service {
  width: 24.8%;
  height: 45%;
  background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div id="servicesGrid">
  <div id="serviceWide" class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
  <div class="service col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#servicesGrid
{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.service
{
  width:calc(24.75% - 1px);
 height:45%;
 background:#262626;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 margin:1px;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(2)
{
 margin-left:0;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(5)
{
 margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="servicesGrid">
  <div id="serviceWide" class="service col" style="width:100%; margin:0 0 1px 0"></div>
<div class="service col"></div>
<div class="service col"></div>
<div class="service col"></div>
<div class="service col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanna work with a fixed 1px margin, you should calc your width (the way the margin is set, it's very hard for you to set a dynamic width without a small exception - unless you want to use `<table>`)

This way, I recommend you to use `width: calc(25% - Ypx)` on your columns. Is supported on the overall browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). This worked out using this:

```
.service
{
    width:calc(25% - 2px);
    height:45%;
    background:#262626;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1px;
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(2)
{
    margin-left:0;
    width:calc(25% - 1px);
}

#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(5)
{
    margin-right:0;
    width:calc(25% - 1px);
}
```