# HTML/CSS Full Width 4 Column Layout With Flush Edges

Tags: css, html

I am trying to implement a full width 4 column layout on a pure HTML/CSS (basically, not using bootstrap) responsive website using this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fourcol">
  <div class="column-fourcol">
    <div class="stockitembox">
      <img src="../resources/graphics/images/product_hexagonal.png" title="Search our hexagonal steel stock range ..." alt="Hexagonal steel bar" onclick="hexagonalFunction()">
      <p>HEXAGONAL</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-fourcol">
    <div class="stockitembox">
      <img src="../resources/graphics/images/product_round.png" title="Search our round steel stock range ..." alt="Round steel bar" onclick="roundFunction()">
      <p>ROUND</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-fourcol">
    <div class="stockitembox">
      <img src="../resources/graphics/images/product_rectangular.png" title="Search our rectangular steel stock range ..." alt="Rectangular steel bar" onclick="rectangularFunction()">
      <p>RECTANGULAR</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-fourcol">
    <div class="stockitembox">
      <img src="../resources/graphics/images/product_square.png" title="Search our square steel stock range ..." alt="Square steel bar" onclick="squareFunction()">
      <p>SQUARE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column-fourcol {
  float: left;
  width:24.3%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.row-fourcol::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media (max-width: 1903px) {
  .column-fourcol {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

My issue is however, when adding spacing (using padding) I have to add padding to the right side meaning that my columns are flush on the left hand side yet not flush on the right hand side as either they do not fill the entire space or it drops down to the next line due to the right hand side padding. I have shown this in the image below, the left hand side is flush to the left border but the right hand side could not be flush as the padding would prevent it.

How could I make a 4 column layout where the columns are spaced but are flush up to the side of the container on both the left and right? I have searched similar question to my own (such as this: [CSS Full-Width Grid - Columns with Even Margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897981/css-full-width-grid-columns-with-even-margins)) however, this example seems to not match my desired effect of spaced columns (or maybe I just do not understand the answer).

[Example of four column padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCmbC.png)
(Red lines for illustration of the sides of the container.)

Thank you for any assistance, all help is much appreciated.

Comment: first of all, to be a rockstar at css world building responsive websites, don't use `float` or `display: table`, use `css grid` or `flexbox`

Comment: Don't put right padding on your last element, or use border-box box-sizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox iis the best solution. But you can try something like this:

```
.column-fourcol {
  float: left;
  width:25%;

}
.stockitembox{
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.row-fourcol::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1903px) {
  .column-fourcol {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

You can see the result in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/n59us5oz/7/

**UPDATE**

You can remove the right and left spacing adding negative margins to the row:
https://jsfiddle.net/n59us5oz/8/

Comment: This solution has padding before the first column and after the last column and would not line up flush with the red lines in the OP's image.

Comment: If you don't like side spacing, just put negative margins to the parent.

.row-fourcol{
margin-left:-5px;
margin-right: -5px;
}

Comment: I am probably going to use your solution, by tinkering with your jfiddle example I found that altering your media query to max width instead of min, and adding a -13 margin, then changing my 45% to 50% width I get the desired effect. I will now just spend some time testing this on my own solution and then ill mark question as answered. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: turns out that a -5px margin (as suggested in the first place) works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use flexbox. Read it here [flexbox tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
 .row-fourcol{
        display:flex;
    }
    .column-fourcol{
        flex:1;
    }
```